# Changing the UI look for Filepicker upload box

Tags: filepicker.io

I just started using filepicker for a application and I want to know if it is allowed to change the standard look and feel of the upload modal, and custom content / CSS on it. If yes, then how ? I wasn't able to see any docs around that.

I am using the following code to invoke the modal (from the docs) -

```
 $('input[type="file"]#ajax-upload').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var output = $("#ajax-upload-output");
filepicker.pick({
mimetypes: ['image/*'],
container: 'modal',
services:['COMPUTER', 'FACEBOOK', 'GMAIL'],
},
 function(FPFile){
console.log(JSON.stringify(FPFile));
output.html('Uploaded: '+FPFile.url+'');

filepicker.convert(FPFile,
        {width: 150, height: 150, fit:'crop', align:'faces'},
        function(bigfp) {
            $("#conversion-150").attr("src", bigfp.url);
    });

 },
 function(progress){
    output.text("Uploading... ("+progress+"%)");
},
 function(FPError){
console.log(FPError.toString());
 });

 });
```

Would truly appreciate any help.

Kind regards,
Titash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can go into your developer portal and add CSS to be included along with the modal. It's under the Customization tab

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate this help.